# How could I achieve this with the least amount of code?

Tags: vb.net, parsing

I currently have a variable with contains 10 characters, being either 1's or 0's, each of which represent a permission key.

Now, as I also have the UAC panel imbedded in my program, I'ld like to have the ability to control who can do what by enableing/disableing features based on that key.

An example of the key would be: `1011001101`.

The control with which I change people's keys, is a list of 10 checkboxes.

E.g. `1000000000` would only give control over the UAC, and all other features can be enabled by checking it's corresponding checkbox in the UAC and updating the key.

How should I be approaching the matter of automatically filling the checkboxes based on the permission key when I select a different user?

Note: Here's a screenshot of how the UAC panel looks for now, just to give you an idea of how my form is set up.

[image: UAC panel]

**EDIT:** Just thought I should give you guys a clear example of what I'm trying to do, so I wrote this massive piece of code, which I know would work, but it'd be too much of a performance hit to actually use in my program like this:

```
If Mid(pkeys, 1, 1) = "1" Then
            chkUAC.Checked = True
        End If
        If Mid(pkeys, 2, 1) = "1" Then
            chkPInv.Checked = True
        End If
        If Mid(pkeys, 3, 1) = "1" Then
            chkVInv.Checked = True
        End If
        If Mid(pkeys, 4, 1) = "1" Then
            chkCheck.Checked = True
        End If
        If Mid(pkeys, 5, 1) = "1" Then
            chkPMap.Checked = True
        End If
        If Mid(pkeys, 6, 1) = "1" Then
            chkVMap.Checked = True
        End If
        If Mid(pkeys, 7, 1) = "1" Then
            chkTele.Checked = True
        End If
        If Mid(pkeys, 8, 1) = "1" Then
            chkHeal.Checked = True
        End If
        If Mid(pkeys, 9, 1) = "1" Then
            chkDart.Checked = True
        End If
        If Mid(pkeys, 10, 1) = "1" Then
            chkWhiteList.Checked = True
        End If
```

Comment: less code is not always the best code.

Comment: True, but I've found that (most of the times) less code means less CPU load/less chance for an AppHang - Also, less is more manageable

Comment: His comment is saying that your observation does not always hold true. In particular, manipulating individual bits is *not* going to be faster than the alternatives.

Comment: Please don't post your answer in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a `List(Of CheckBox)` that holds a reference to each permission checkbox in the order that you have the bits in the permission key.

Then, when your `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event is fired, you take the permission key of the selected user and convert it to a char array.

Then loop through that char array while iterating an index value so that you can set the `cbList[index].checked` equal to the boolean value of the current char.

---

It would be something like this:

You would declare the List:

```
Dim cbList = New List(Of CheckBox)
```

Somewhere you would initialize it:

```
With cbList

    .Add(chkUAC)
    .Add(chkPInv)
    .Add(chkVInv)
    .Add(chkCheck)
    .Add(chkPMap)
    .Add(chkVMap)
    .Add(chkTele)
    .Add(chkHeal)
    .Add(chkDart)
    .Add(chkWhiteList)

End With
```

Then you would loop through and assign on index changed:

```
Protected Sub ddlUser_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlUser.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim i = 0

    For Each c In ddlUser.SelectedValue.ToCharArray

        cbList(i).Checked = c = "1"
        i += 1

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, every array I've used so far had seperate inputs for each index, how would I go about converting 1 variable into a char array? Simply with `mid(String,x,y)`?

Comment: Help me understand. I thought `1011001101` was a string that represented the turning off on of each individual checkbox.  Is that not so?

Comment: The `xxxxxxxxxx` key simply has each digit representing an enabled feature for the user, if it's `1111111111` (for example) that means the user in question has all possible features, and thus will have all checkboxes checked when the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` is fired. Simply put, each digit represents wether or not a checkbox should be checked or not.

Comment: Exactly. So what I said would work.  All you do is add each checkbox in the position order of where it is located in that key into a List(Of Checkbox). I called mine cbList.  So now you have an index based list of checkboxes that you can immediately access by position order of your key by cbList(index).  So when you pull the value of that user dropdown, I'm assuming that's the key.  You just do ToCharArray() on it.  Now you have the same order that your checkboxes are in with cbList.  You just loop through the char array, converting that char to it's boolean value and set cbList(index) = bool.

Comment: I see, great idea right there, some sort of iteration was definately the kind of thing I thought would be most efficient in my case, I just had no clue on how 2 get it all into an array because the key is retrieved from a MySQL database :P

Answer (score 2):

This pretty much sound like bitwise comparison but using a string instead of an integer. If still possible, I would suggest switching to integers so that you can use binary operators to do the check.

Instead of having "1011001101", you would have integer 717. If you wanted to check that against "1000000000" (integer 512), you could simple do a check like this:

```
' iPerm = 717, iUACMask = 512
chkUAC.Checked = CBool(iPerm And iUACMask)
```

If iPerm includes iUACMask, the expression will evaluate to a non-zero value resulting in True. If it does not match, it will return 0.

If changing to integers is no longer possible, you could do an on-the-fly converstion of that. Obviously performance will be worse than when using integers to begin with, but depending on the use that might not be an issue.

```
' strPerm = "1011001101", strUACMask = "1000000000"
chkUAC.Checked = CBool(Convert.ToInt32(strPerm, 2) And Convert.ToInt32(strUACMask, 2))
```

Comment: I have been thinking about something similar aswell, but I'm using this type of permission key in 2 many forms allready & too much code depends on it allready for me 2 just let go of it, although you're idea is probably better, I really don't feel like redoing like 40% of my current code

Comment: It should be an enum marked with [`FlagAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx).

Comment: I agree.  It should be flag enum

Answer (score 0):

Simply change this code

```
For x = 0 To 9
  If pkeys(x) = "1" Then
    cbList(x).Checked = True
  Else
    cbList(x).Checked = False
  End If
Next
```

To this code

```
For x = 0 To 9
  cbList(x).Checked = (pkeys(x) = "1")
Next
```